# Phone number with dropdown country code vue js not working?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, dropdown

I am following this link: https://codepen.io/otuzel/pen/PooBoQW?editors=1011
but giving error  Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?
i have installed plugin --> npm install vue-tel-input

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
  <v-form>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>        
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
        <vue-tel-input v-bind="bindProps" v-model="phone" v-on:country-changed="countryChanged"></vue-tel-input>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  <v-btn
    color="success"
    @click="submit"
  >
    submit
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

in script

```
<script>
export default {

 data() {
return {
  phone: null,
  country: null,
  bindProps: {
    mode: "international",
    placeholder: "Enter a phone number",
    required: false,
    enabledCountryCode: true,
    enabledFlags: true,
    autocomplete: "off",
    name: "telephone",
    maxLen: 25,
    inputOptions: {
      showDialCode: true
    }
  }
}
},
methods: {
countryChanged(country) {
 this.country = '+' + country.dialCode
},
submit() {
  console.log(this.phone)
  console.log(this.country)
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

giving error Unknown custom element: - did you register the component correctly? Why it is happening?
i have installed plugin --> npm install vue-tel-input

Comment: The page https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input#installation says on how to install the plugin into Vue

Comment: when i am trying your page link  it is giving me error: This relative module was not found:

* ./tel-input-field.vue in ./src/main.js @Anees

Comment: Have you installed tel-input-field from npm?

Comment: yes i have installed,  "vue-tel-input": "^4.4.0",